# How to handle json stringified with rabbitListener?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm sending an Json object to my restController and one of it´s properties is a String field that will receive a json Stringified object.

JSON sent by postman request:

```
{
  "queueName":"queue.sample",
  "message": "{\"id\" : \"89EA5456\",\"cob\" : \"17\",\"apo\" : \"999999\"}"
}
```

Here we can see the message content:

```
public void sendMessage(MessageDto message) {

    this.rabbitService.convertAndSend(   message.getQueueName(), 
                                         message.getMessage());
    log.info("Mensagem enviada - queue: {} - message: {}", message.getQueueName(), message.getMessage());
        
}

Mensagem enviada - queue: queue.sample - message: {"id": "89EA5456","cob": "17","numApo" : "999999"}
```

The problem is happening in the consumer part of the process.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue.sample")
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    log.info("Mensagem consumida: "+ new String(message.getBody()));
}
```

Mensagem consumida: **"**{\"id\" : \"89EA5456\",\"cob\" : \"17\",\"apo\" : \"999999\"}**"**

Why did these quotes (in beginning and in the end of the message) and the escape chars come with the message?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` on the sending side (instead of the default `SimpleMessageConverter`? That converter will re-encode the string. Show your template configuration.

Comment: I'm testing rabbitMQ so was using producer/consumer in the same project and I was using Jackson2JsonMessageConverter indeed. I've change to the default messageConverter and solved my problema. Tks!

Comment: You can add as an answer to your own question and accept it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Gary. I was indeed using Jackson2JsonMessageConvert. I've changed to use the default message converter in the sending side and solved the problem.